# jQuery.Ajax вывести результат в элемент div

Tags: jquery, ajax

Есть страница с некоторыми ссылками:
**index.php**:

```
<a href="#" id="1">Текст 1</a>
<a href="#" id="2">Текст 2</a>
<a href="#" id="3">Текст 3</a>

....

<div id="ajaxDiv"></div>
```

Есть файл, который принимает параметр id:  **images.php**?id=....

Каким образом нужно сделать Ajax запрос, чтобы в файл images передавался ID ссылки, и результат выводить в `<div id="ajaxDiv">`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно прописать ссылкам один общий класс:

```
<a href="#" class="my_class" id="1">Текст 1</a>
<a href="#" class="my_class" id="2">Текст 2</a>
<a href="#" class="my_class" id="3">Текст 3</a>
```

Потом навесить на них событие вот так:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $('.my_class').click(function() {
            var id=$(this).attr("id");
            jQuery.post('images.php?id='+id, {},
                function(data) {
                    $("#ajaxDiv").text(data);
                }
            );
        });
    });
```

Comment: Вот только странно то, что функция срабатывает при клике только по ПЕВОЙ ссылке. На клики по остальным ссылкам - тишина. класс у ссылок общий....

Comment: попробуйте изменить
var id=$(this).id;
на
var id=$(this).attr("id");

Comment: спасибо, работает. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var id=$(this).attr("id")
```

А в ajax запросе `data: id`

В ответе:

```
$("#ajaxDiv").text(responseText)
```

Примерно так.

Comment: <a href="#" id="images" title="images.php?id=$id">Text 1</a>   
....  


  $("#a_images").click(function(event) {
     var title_link = $(this).attr("title");
            alert(title_link);
     $.ajax({ 
     url: title_link, 
     type:"GET", 
     success: function(){
     $("#ajaxMethod").text(responseText); 
     } 
     }); 
     });  

откуда взять этот самый ResponseText?

Comment: В переменной response будет ответ сервера

    success: function(response){
        alert(response);
    }

Answer (score 2):

Лучше тогда вместо

```
href="#" id="1"
```

сделать

```
href="#" onclick='имя_функции(1); return false;'
```

и так далее во всех. Вот вам и придет ваш ID в функцию, а дальше уже или аякс, если надо обновить что-то или просто ищите элемент на странице и меняете ему адрес, или текст, или что угодно.

**Добавлено.**

```
href="#" onclick='finik(1); return false;'
```

Остальные соответственно 2 и 3 и так далее, затем сама функция

```
function finik(id) {
    $.post('адрес_куда_запрос', {
        id: id,
        имя: 'переменная'
    }
    function (dates) {
        $("#ajaxDiv").text(dates);
        $("#ИД_рисунка").attr('src', 'images.php?id=' + id);
    });    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#" id="1">Текст 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="2">Текст 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="3">Текст 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="ajaxDiv"></div>
```

и

```
$(function(){
    $('ul.nav a').bind('click',function(){
        var id=$(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:'images.php',
            data:'id='+id,
            dataType:'html',
            success:function(data){
               $('#ajaxDiv').html(data);
            },
            error:function(){alert('Error!')}
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xYKsw/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#a_images').click(function(){
var id=$(this).attr('id');
$.post('image.php',
     {"id":id),
     function(result)
    {
        $('#ajaxDiv').html(result);
    });

});
```

result - это ответ от сервера. данные идут методом пост.

Comment: Переделал, слегка, но всё равно не работает:

    $('#a_images').click(function () {
        var title_link = $(this).attr("title");
        alert(title_link);
        $.post(title_link), function (result) {
            $('#ajaxMethod').html(result);
            alert(result);
        };

    });

Comment: Канеш не работает) ты ж в пост параметры $_GET пихаешь. И зачем в title их писать? не понятно. Если хочешь в строке передать то тогда $.get(url,function(res){
   //do something
});